# Extract Pattern String From Sentence and replace another string

Tags: c#

I have a following string

```
If(objid1+objid2=5;Len("Test");Len("T"))
```

Looking for Regular Expression to convert `Objid1`to`Obj("1")`

Because I have inbuilt function which supports `Obj("1")` not `objid1` and don't want to change my existing function as another module using this function

So above statement looks like

```
If(obj("1")+obj("2")=5;Len("Test");Len("T"))
```

`Objid` + any number max to 3 digit

Means `objid{n}...... objid{nnn}`

Can anybody help me out for regex Expression to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a named capture group:

`objid(?<id>\d{0,3})`

such as:

```
var str = @"If(objid1+objid2=5;Len(""Test"");Len(""T""))";
var str2 = Regex.Replace(str, @"objid(?<id>\d{0,3})", @"obj(""${id}"")");

//str2 = If(obj("1")+obj("2")=5;Len("Test");Len("T"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, you may want to enable case insensitive regex matching also:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "objid(\\d+)", "obj(\"$1\")")
```